# How ConvertAll<Guid>(Guid.Parse) works?

Tags: c#, refactoring

First I had this kind of line

```
List<Guid> ratingComparisonIds = ratingComparison.ConvertAll<Guid>(o => Guid.Parse(o));
```

Then ReSharper gave me a hint that I could convert it to method group. Result of that operation is this

```
List<Guid> ratingComparisonIds = ratingComparison.ConvertAll<Guid>(Guid.Parse);
```

I am confused about the syntax.. how and why does it work? I mean there is no parameters for the parse method. Magic I would say.

**Update**

Even more compact conversion

```
List<Guid> ratingComparisonIds = ratingComparison.ConvertAll(Guid.Parse);
```

Comment: The "Update" is using generic type inference - but note that this may compile differently (i.e. fail) on a C# 2.0 compiler, since generic type inference in C# 2.0 is nowhere near as strong as in C# 3.0. I'm "all for" the version in the "Update", though - unless you need to compile on older compilers for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's using a *method group conversion*. It's doing something like this:

```
// Very long-winded C# 1 syntax
Converter<String, Guid> converter = new Converter<String, Guid>(Guid.Parse);
List<Guid> ratingComparisonIds = ratingComparison.ConvertAll(converter);

// Simpler C# 2 syntax
Converter<String, Guid> converter = Guid.Parse;
List<Guid> ratingComparisonIds = ratingComparison.ConvertAll(converter);
```

Now inline the variable, and you get to the original code. Does that make things clearer?

Comment: It makes more sense now. Method group conversion seems to be clever thing. I wish I could design my API's in a similar way. Sometimes I have a feeling that C# is evolving so fast that I never understand even the old features. :)

Answer (score 3):

`ConvertAll` (in this context) takes here requires a `Converter<string,Guid>` - a delegate to a method that takes a `string` and returns a `Guid`. The static `Guid.Parse` satisfies that *perfectly* - exactly the same  as if we had written `new Converter<string,Guid>(Guid.Parse)`, or written:

```
Converter<string,Guid> conv = Guid.Parse; // perfectly valid
List<Guid> ratingComparisonIds = ratingComparison.ConvertAll<Guid>(conv);
```

The *lambda* version adds a level of indirection via an anonymous method:

```
static Guid <>____blah(string o) { return Guid.Parse(o); }
```

so the direct call to `Guid.Parse` is actually *marginally* more efficient.

Comment: Good explanation, thank you. It's a shame that I can't mark two answers. +1 vote